# log->read("$file")....Out of memory error

Tags: perl

7G of tcpdump data in to perl script,

I was thrown out from the program with "Out Of memory !".

can anyone give some suggestions.

Thankyou,

```
$log = Net::TcpDumpLog->new();
$log->read("$file");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to read the entire file into memory.  From the entry on CPAN:

> TODO
>
> Future versions should include the
>   ability to write as well as read
>   tcpdump logs. Also a memory efficient
>   technique to process very large
>   tcpdump logs (where the log size is
>   greater than available virtual
>   memory).

So there's currently no way using that package to process a 1.7GB file unless you have enough memory to load it completely.